# page source and inspect element do not have same data

Tags: javascript, php, html, curl

From time to time I like to use php to grab some data using cURL.

Typically, I will use a particular link, and get the source of the page, then isolate the text I am looking for, and save it to my MySql database.

In this case, there is a value I am trying to get at. In the source, I see:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="hdnOrignalEstdValue" id="hdnOrignalEstdValue" />
```

which does not have the value.

But in the 'Inspect Element' console I see this:

```
<input tabindex="0" value="1768000" name="hdnOrignalEstdValue" id="hdnOrignalEstdValue" type="hidden">
```

This inspect element console sees the "hdnOrignalEstdValue" field, *and* shows the value (which you can see looking at the web page after you navigate to the link)

I have scoured the source code, and checked every link, and looked at the code for every related link, but the "1768000" can't be found anywhere. Since I see it showing up under 'Inspect Element', I know it is being delivered to my computer somehow, but I don't know how to code php, and/or use a different version of cURL, or some other method to 'find' that number.

Comment: It could be added via JavaScript....try disabling JS in your browser and seeing if the 1768000 is still there?

Comment: PHP is serve-rside so you would see it in the source if it were added there. As @onsmith said, check your JavaScript. If your inspected code doesn't match your source, it's being modified client-side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Turning off JS did not do the trick, but what did was taking a closer look at the headers where I was able to find a more reliable link to access the data.